# How to geneate media:content xml using php

Tags: php, xml

i facing few issue's i don't know how to resolve it

i want to write following rss feed using php and mysql:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rss version="2.0">
<channel>
<item>
<title>Here is the title</title>
<link>http://example.com</link>
<media:content medium="image" url="http://example.com/image.jpg"></media:content>
<media:content medium="video" url="http://example.com/video.mp4"></media:content>
</item>
</channel>
</rss>
```

here is my code in php:

```
$db = new Db();

    $result = $db->select("select * from column");

    $xml = new SimpleXMLElement('<channel/>');


    for ($i = 0; $i < count($result); $i++) {

        $title = $result[$i]title
        $link = $result[$i]['link'];
        $image = $result[$i]['image'];
    $video = $result[$i]['video'];

        $item = $xml->addChild('item');

        $item->title = $title 
        $item->link = $link
        $item->image = ?? ;
        $item->video = ?? ;       

    }
    Header('Content-type: text/xml');
    print($xml->asXML());
```

just don't know how to set image and video because there tags are different like media:content and url of both image and video tags. please let me know

thanks

Comment: Namespace prefix, such as `media` in your XML, need to be declared somewhere (something along this line: `xmlns:media="foo"`). As posted the XML is not well-formed. Now, on which element do you want the ns prefix declaration to be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not do that. Your XML is not valid. Prefixed tags must have a declared NameSpace URI, in your case 'http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/':

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rss version="2.0" xmlns:media="http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/">
(...)
</rss>
```

You can use `->addChild` to create namespaced elements:

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rss version="2.0" xmlns:media="http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/">
<channel/>
</rss>');

(...)

$item = $xml->channel->addChild('item');

$item->title = $title;
$item->link  = $link;

/* Add <media:image>: */
$node = $item->addChild( 'image', Null, 'http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/' );
$node->addAttribute( 'url', $image );

/* Add <media:video>: */
$node = $item->addChild( 'video', Null, 'http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/' );
$node->addAttribute( 'url', $video );
```

Result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rss xmlns:media="http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/" version="2.0">
    <channel>
        <item>
            <title>Your Title</title>
            <link>http://www.somelink.it/</link>
            <media:image url="http://www.image.com/"/>
            <media:video url="http://www.video.com/"/>
        </item>
    </channel>
</rss>
```

Comment: you are genius thanks so much, please just let me know last thing my xml image medium in media content tag please can you just clear this out: `<media:content medium="image"
url="http://www.website.com/image.jpg"></media:content>` xml site given to me is [link](http://news.yahoo.com/rss/)

Comment: I don't understand. Please clarify

Comment: because as you said media tag which is little bit different in myside must requirement is opening and closing tag of media content like that example `<media:content medium="image" url="http://www.website.com/image.jpg"></media:content>`

Comment: you example is working fine but it's didn't show the image in rss feed !! [link](http://news.yahoo.com/rss/) the image is shown in rss !! so in your example rss images is not show i must have show the images in rss as well please help me out there requirement is must opening and close tag of media:content

Comment: In XML tags w/out node value are self-closed by `<tag ... />`, not by `<tag></tag>`. For `<media:content>` follow above example: `$item->addChild( 'content', ... )`, then `->addAttribute( 'url', value )`. You can add more than one attribute. See [here](http://www.rssboard.org/media-rss#media-content) for availble attributes for media:content.

Comment: thanks so much you are help me lot and i done successful !